# Finding the Weibull Distribution from the Exponential

Tags: probability, exponential-function, distribution-theory

I've been asked to find the Weibull Distribution using a previously known distribution, which in this case is the Exponential. Could anyone assist me?

Comment: See if this helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497491/relation-between-weibull-and-exponential-distributions

Comment: Google "derive the weibull distribution from the exponential one".